# Socat exclusive lock to PTY

Tags: locking, socat

I would like only one process to open the PTY device created by socat.
I used the following to create `my_ser` device, but it can be read / written by multiple processes.

`socat -t 0 INTERFACE:my_nw,type=2 PTY,mode=0777,rawer,link=/dev/my_ser`

I tried to used 
`socat -t 0 INTERFACE:my_nw,type=2 PTY,mode=0777,rawer,link=/dev/my_ser,ioctl-void=0x540c` to use the PTY exclusive lock (TIOCEXCL), but it does not work.
I can see the IOCTL being executed, but with no effect.

I am running on Ubuntu machine

Comment: What are you trying to achieve as such?

Comment: That the character PTY device created /dev/my_ser should not be opened by two application. This device is translating the serial write to a network interface.

Comment: See if this test is of any help? https://github.com/craSH/socat/blob/c20699fced66696e243d785fdfcd2a94cf11e4cc/test.sh#L10568

Comment: I had a look at the test case already, it is using a PIPE to communicate between PTY and file. In my case it is between network interface and PTY. So I am not sure on how to map it to my use-case. I tried to introduce an intermediate pipe, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Not sure then what else could be done. I guess someone with better understanding around this area would be able to comment better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understood now the TIOCEXCL flag in more detail. The application opening the PTY terminal should use this flag to obtain the exclusive lock. If we use it during PTY creation in socat command, it has no effect. But it does not give any error as well.

Thus the application should call the ioctl flag and it should be removed from here.